# Can Windows AD/DC cause PCs to freeze or lock up and what would those reasons be?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

I figured I'd throw this one out there, cause it has stumped me, thus far.

A number of Windows workstations, not all, have had their computers lock up once a day. Sometimes multiple times in a day. Reboot seems to fix it for a day. Many users just leave their computer screen locked and then unlock it the next day. There might be some who log off Windows and then log back in, without turning their computer off, but probably not.

When I say lock up, I don't mean for a few seconds. It's indefinite. Ctrl-alt-delete doesn't work. They have to reboot their PCs. Again, only some people have had this issue.

I isolated one user. I figured if I set UAC to not dim the deskop or just turn UAC off, the problem would be masked. It was. Many of these users reported that their PC would lock up when clicking on something that requires elevated privileges, i.e. Secure Desktop. By disabling Secure Desktop, the screen doesn't dim and cause the video driver to essentially freeze the PC indefinitely. My thought process was put update the video driver with a reference driver or the latest version, put the PC back in UAC Default, and observe if the problem persists.

Some users had the issue just clicking in IE. No elevated privileges. PC would lock up and the users would have to restart. Maybe they are two different but related issues.

Today, it appears that the PC lock up issue, thus far, has resolved itself. No new Windows Updates. The leading theory is Active Directory / Domain Controller was causing the workstations to lock up. Can someone please explain how this is possible? I can see momentarily freezing for things like querying network shares, sure. But a total PC lock up? Would could cause this from a server end? Local Group Policy? Could a bad SAN or switch cause this? Or a severed connection from the AD/DC to the workstations that were affected?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All of the things you mention could possibly cause the problem but now would not likely fix themselves. I would check the eventvwr of the affected machines, and double-check no changes have been made to drivers on those machines. Total freeze-ups could be video drivers, or could be a runaway process on the local machines.

Comment: Thank you. Well, there was nothing of note in event viewer. No runaway processes. No driver updates. Those were ruled out some time ago. This only started recently. Hence, after looking everywhere else, the idea is now this is AD/DC and/or SAN/network related. I just never thought that something on the AD/DC could cause an X number of workstations to just freeze indefinitely.